# Remove whitespace from Spark list image item with 100% width

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder, flex4.5

I'm new to Flex and am going through a personal task list for learning purposes. Currently working with lists for displaying an image array. My last 5 images are larger than the list dimensions. When I set width="100%" for the images, it adds whitespace/padding above and below the image. Having a 'mare trying to get rid of it. Here's the code:

```
<s:List id="fgList" left="{width * 0.2}" height="100%" width="75%"
        useVirtualLayout="false" pageScrollingEnabled="false"
        verticalScrollPolicy="on" horizontalScrollPolicy="off"
        contentBackgroundAlpha="0" itemRenderer="{null}">
    <s:layout>
        <s:VerticalLayout requestedRowCount="-1" variableRowHeight="true" gap="10"/>
    </s:layout>
    <s:dataProvider>
        <s:ArrayList id="fgImages">
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/fg-v1-img001.png')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/fg-v1-img002.png')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/003.jpg')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/004.jpg')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/005.jpg')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/006.jpg')" width="100%"/>
            <s:Image source="@Embed('assets/007.jpg')" width="100%"/>
        </s:ArrayList>
    </s:dataProvider>
</s:List>
```

An explanation as to why it behaves as such would be beneficial. Suspect the list generates the image rows first before the image resize action takes place hence the whitespace. This doesn't affect the first 2 images as they're at the exact width dimension as the list. So do I need some sort of ItemRenderer/Script to resize the list rows after image creation complete?

Thanks

[Edit] Well I've resolved this issue thanks to a little script I found and adapted. Sharing for those in need:

```
private function imageLoaded(event:Event):void {
    var img:Image = event.target as Image;
    img.scaleX = img.scaleY = (fgList.width / img.sourceWidth);
}
```

Call function via creationComplete:

```
<s:Image source="@Embed('assets/fg-v1-img001.png')" smooth="true" creationComplete="imageLoaded(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two properties you need to look at here. [`Image.scaleMode`](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Image.html#scaleMode) and [`Image.fillMode`](http://flex.apache.org/asdoc/spark/components/Image.html#fillMode).

By default, `fillMode` is set to `scale`, which will scale the image to the specified size. This is what you want. The other options are `clip`, which will display the image at its actual size and just mask the area outside of the specified dimensions, and `repeat`, which will repeat the image if the specified dimensions are larger.

So `scaleMode` is what you need to change. By default, it is set to `letterbox`, which letterboxes the image. It scales the image until it hits one of the limits of the region while keeping the original aspect ratio. If the aspect ratio of the image and region are different, it stops as soon as it hits that first limit, leaving whitespace on the edges. This is the same effect you get when watching most movies on your TV, since movies are generally a different aspect ratio than the 16:9 your TV uses. That is currently what you are experiencing.

The other two options, `stretch` and `zoom`, will change the aspect ratio to match the specified area. `stretch` will, as its name suggests, stretch both axises to fill the region. This will, by definition, distort the image's proportions. The option you need is `zoom`, which will scale the image until the entire region has been filled. This *will* push portions of the image out of the visible area, though. In general, however, it is the best option and there really is no way to avoid it other than using the correct aspect ratio. Additionally, this will center the image both vertically and horizontally. I'm unsure if you can change that; I have honestly never tried.

```
<s:Image source="@Embed('assets/007.jpg')" width="100%" scaleMode="zoom"/>
```

The above code should do the trick. You may also need to specify a height, though, I am unsure. I know I end up testing that every time I use `zoom` and never seem to remember what the answer is.

Comment: Thanks. Zoom crops the image, which I cannot allow on my foreground content. The entire width of my image has to display, which originally resulted in borders at the top and bottom. With zoom, the image gets a horizontalAlign=centre causing content to be lost on either side. I am however using zoom for my background image. Still, welcome any other solutions if they're better than the one I've currently implemented [the imageLoaded function].

Comment: Unfortunately, your choices are either stretch the image so that its aspect ratio is wrong and the image is distorted (`stretch`) or hide a portion of either the top and bottom or the left and right edges. (`zoom`). There is no other way to do it. You can't show the entire image without distortion. That is just what happens when you change aspect ratio